# SignalR client pure HTML

Tags: signalr.client

can anyone shed me some light how to create a pure HTML SignalR Client (non asp.net)? 
How do i connect this client to the existing asp.net hub server?

what do i need to change from the code below, if contosoChatHub is in other asp.net application

```
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Javascript Client: [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

Comment: i did.. what i dont understand how the client knows the hubconnection if the hub server (hub.cs) is in totally different directory?   var connection = $.hubConnection();
        var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');

Comment: @user384080: you missed this part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#client-setup . It is part of the tutorial